# Why is my stripe invoice showing 0 as total?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am trying to create a one time charge with a pdf invoice with Laravel Cashier for stripe.
The form submit successfuly, however, the invoice total is 0 and there is no payment in the Stripe page of payment list.

I have created one product with multiple price.
I saved the price ids in a table with the product name.

[image: Stripe invoice]

```php
public function purchase(Request $request, SubscriptionPlan $subscriptionPlan)
    {
        try {

            auth()->user()->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
            auth()->user()->updateStripeCustomer(['address' => ['country' => 'CA'],'preferred_locales' => ['fr-CA']]);
            auth()->user()->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($request->paymentMethod);
            auth()->user()->invoicePrice($subscriptionPlan->stripe_price_id, 1);  // Product ID from stripe   
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            \Log::debug($exception->getMessage());
            return back()->with('error', $exception->getMessage());
        }

        return back()->with('success', 'Paiement effectué avec succès!');
    }
```

Edit:
I found that there are as many "pending invoice items" as $0 invoices.
[Pending invoice items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFzTs.png)

Comment: It would be easier if you reach out to Stripe Support or their Discord server and provide a specific Invoice Id (in_xxx) to check. It's hard to tell just from your screenshot.

There could be reasons for an Invoice having 0 amount, like the Customer has some coupon applied, or it's a subscription with trial, etc

Answer (score 0):

it sound likes a [subscription with a trial period](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials), where the first invoice is $0.

Did you specify a [trial_period_days](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_period_days) or [trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_end) when creating this subscription? If not, you can reach out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) and give them the subscription ID to investigate further.

Comment: I had no succes yet with the support to figure out what is wrong.
I investiguated further on my own, and found that there are as many "pending invoice items" as $0 invoices.